# iTunes file sharing with iOS device on windows

Tags: objective-c, ios6, file-sharing

I have modified my info.plist with "Application supports iTunes file sharing" = YES.

File sharing is working perfectly fine when using a Mac machine, but if I save a file on a windows machine, it gives me a blank file (0 kb data). iTunes shows me the correct size for the file.
I am using the latest version of iTunes.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: What sort of files are you talking about?  Are you talking about ones with a common file type like png, txt, jpg?  And which Windows OS version is it?  Windows 7 64-bit?  32-bit?

Comment: I'm trying to save data to a csv file, and I have tried it on test machines with both 32 bit and 64 bit Windows 7. Can there be a possibility of encoding being the issue here? I'm using NSUTF8StringEncoding